# Symfony2 : How return Response in specified route format when an exception is thrown in controller?

Tags: json, symfony

When i call this controller, with route specifying JSON format :

```php
class MyController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/", defaults={"_format"="json"}))
   * @Method({"GET"})
   */
  public function indexAction(Request $request)
  {
      throw new \Exception('foo');
  }
}
```

I obtain a response with json Content-Type header, but its body (with error message) is in html.

However, from this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html, i thought Twig choose template from specified format (and status code), for example "error.json.twig" ?

I would like obtain a json response as :

```
{ error : "foo" ... }
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... This is a new issue, now pulled in symfony github : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/9084#commits-pushed-39d55de